# PHP echo JSON value from nested array

Tags: php

I'm calling a REST/JSON api from an php page.
This is an sample successful JSON response:

```
{
   "code": 0,
   "message": "",
   "objects":
   {
      "UserRequest::123":
      {
         "code": 0,
         "message": "created",
         "class": "UserRequest",
         "key": 29,
         "fields":
         {
            "id": 29,
            "friendlyname": "R-000029"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I just want to echo the `id` value in the page, but I can't get it to work.
I have tried to json_decode the response

```
$decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);
```

and if I `print_r` the decoded response, it will look something like this:

```
Array ( [objects] => Array ( [UserRequest::17282] => Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => created [class] => UserRequest [key] => 17282 [fields] => Array ( [id] => 17282 ) ) ) [code] => 0 [message] => )
```

Comment: You can just go through your array and retrieve the id. Like this: `$decoded_response['objects']['UserRequest::17282']['fields']['id']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Read about [accessing values in PHP arrays using square brackets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it like this:

```
foreach( $decoded_response['objects'] as $k=>$v) {
    if ( isset($v['key']) ) {
      echo 'Ticket created: ', $v['fields']['friendlyname'], "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the nested id by following the deep elements this way,

```
echo $decoded_response['objects']['UserRequest::123']['fields']['id'];
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/nUtUe